# amCharts and left/right keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, amcharts

I want to implement keyboard navigation to amCharts using left and right arrow keys. I'm using only `amCharts.js` without stock chart.

Is it possible and how can this be done?

Comment: What should those key presses do? Pan selection left/right?

Comment: Yes, i need to display values from amCharts and only left/right keys guarantee the best precision.
I have more than 10.000 values in this chart.

Comment: 10K data points on a Serial chart? That sounds like an overhead. Any chance of putting together a fiddle/codepen demo of your chart with data?

Comment: It's not overhead. Works just fine.
I present data from 1 year with 15 minutes gap on a single chart.
But i need better navigation than mouse.

Comment: Alright. Your question would benefit from a working example then. Do you think you can put that together?

Comment: Formatted contents and fixed grammar.